# this in template literals inside objects

Tags: object, this, string-literals

```
const me = {
  fName: "Marc",
  mName: "Fenzy",
  lName: "Antenor",
  friends: ["Julbert", "Gracia", "Ralph", "Mackendy", "Roselaure", "Wilny"],
  randFriend: function(){
    let friendIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.friends.length));
    
    return `Name of a good friend of mine? It's ${this.friends[friendIndex]}.`;
  },
  family: {
    dad: "Jesmane",
    mom: "Raymonde",
    brother: ["Kenley", "Dave", "Sammy"],
  },
  birthYear: 1992,
  calcAge: function () {
    this.age = 2023 - this.birthYear;
    return this.age;
  },
  myState: 'miami',
  zipCode: 33169,
  address: `1140 nw 155th ln, apt 105, ${this.State}, ${this.zipCode}.`,
  // address: function(){
  //   return `1140 nw 155th ln, apt 105, ${this.myState}, ${this.zipCode}.`;
  // },
};

const location = me.address;
console.log(location);

// const location = me.address();
// console.log(location);
```

I spent 30 min to realized that. Each time I printed location, the myState and the zipcode would return undefined. Meanwhile, on the previous examples I was working using template literals, it was working fine. Then I realized the common factor between them is the fact that they were inside of a function.
When I set address inside of a function(as shown commented), it printed it fine. I think it has to do with the this property but can't wrap my head arround it. could someone help explain?